# Approximate recursion defined by alternating summation?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, approximation, interpolation

**Problem & Question**

> Given a constant $k\ge 2$, we define the sequence $a_k(0)=0,a_k(1)=1$ and for $n\ge2$:
>
> $$
> a_k(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]} (-1)^{n-i+1} a_k(i)
> $$
>
> Where $\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]$ gives integer part of $\frac{n}{k}$. (The $\left[\space\right]$ represents truncation.)

For example, for $k=2$ we have the following scatterplot: [[Click to see animated gif]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oFSo.gif).

It appear as two interchanging curves repeat [[following shape]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjCe.png) in larger forms as we increase $n$.

> Given $k$, can we find a real equation that would approximate "the curves" given by $a_k(n)$?

That is, the plot given by $a_k(n)$ can be defined as $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ where $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ are those "the curves".

Specifically, $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ are graphs of two real functions $\gamma_1(x),\gamma_2(x)$ where $\gamma_1(x)=-\gamma_2(x)$ as they are symmetric over $y$-axis. The goal is to define them for $x\in\mathbb R$. Currently, you can say that $a_k(n)$ approximates $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ at points $x=n\in\mathbb N$.

If it is not clear what I mean, clicking on the previous link "[following shape]", you can see the curve above the $y$-axis as $\Gamma_1$ given by $\gamma_1(n)$, and the curve below $y$-axis as $\Gamma_2$ given by $\gamma_2(n)$.

For simplicity, we can restrict ourselves to $k=2$ if needed.

**My idea**

The curves $\gamma_1(n)\approx-\gamma_2(n)$ generated by $a_k(n)$ remind me of a sine function whose period is being stretched by some function $g(n)$, and whose amplitude is being increased by some function $h(n)\ne 0$.

Is it possible to find such $g,h$ such that the following "sine form":

$$f_k(x):=h_k(x)\sin\left(\pi g_k(x)\right)\approx \gamma_1(x)=-\gamma_2(x)\space ?$$

To answer my question? This needs to be defined for all real $x\gt 0$.

Notice the above $f_k(x)$ form would have roots (be zero) at $x=g_k^{-1}(m),m\in\mathbb N$.

That is, lets observe "near-zeros" of the sequence $a_k(n)$ - The points where the curves pass over the $y$-axis and and are closest to it. Here are first couple "near-zeros" for $k=2$:

$$a_2(n)\approx 0 \text{ at } n\approx 2,4.5,12.5,33.5,84.5,204.5,480.5,1102.5,2494.5,5568.5,\dots$$

Meaning that the $f_k$ (the $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$) should be zero (have a root) somewhere near these "near-zeros". In the context of my "sine form" $f$ mentioned above, and for $k=2$, this means that we want to find $g_2$ such that for $m=1,2,3,\dots$ we have:

$$ g_2^{-1}(m)=2,4.5,12.5,33.5,84.5,204.5,480.5,1102.5,2494.5,5568.5,\dots $$

For example, here is the plot of $a(n)$ for $n\le215$ showing a near-zero around $n\approx204.5$, where we have $a(204)=-a(205)=-40\approx0$. (Hence I've taken $n\approx \frac{204+205}{2} = 204.5$)

[image]

But, the problem here is:

> - How to determine at which $n$ will $a_k(n)$ reach a "near-zero"?

The other problem that needs to be solved, is to find $h_k(n)$. For starters we need to know the growth of the absolute value of the sequence, $|a_k(n)|$? Then, the question remains:

> - Can we interpolate (approximate) a "closed form" of $h_k(n)$, to get the "amplitude" of $f_k$?

Alternatively, is there a better $f_k$ form to search for, than my "sine form" $f_k$?

Comment: $n \bmod n\equiv 0$ so the last term is always pointless.

Comment: Ones close to 0 so far have 1,1,2,3 prime factors, or 2,2,4,6 divisors.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I decided to simplify the recursion by getting rid of the modulo.

Comment: yeah it was mostly the fact that n like had many factors less than n/2.

Comment: Also nice to note that $|a_k(n)|$ only changes at points where $n$ is a multiple of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but we're getting somewhere.

First note that for $l < k$ and $n>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
a_k(kn+l) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{kn+l-i+1}a_k(i) = (-1)^l a_k(kn)
\end{align*}
Therefore, for any $j \geq 1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=jk}^{jk+k-1} (-1)^{n-i+1}a_k(i) = k(-1)^{n-jk+1}a_k(jk)
\end{align*}
We use this to find the following sum.
\begin{align*}
a_k(k^2n+k^2-k) =& \sum_{i=1}^{kn+k-1} (-1)^{k^2n+k^2-k-i+1}a_k(i) \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^{kn+k-1} (-1)^{k^2n-i+1}a_k(i) \\
=& (-1)^{k^2n} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=jk}^{jk+k-1} (-1)^{k^2n-i+1}a_k(i) \\
=& (-1)^{k^2n} + k\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{k^2n-jk+1}a_k(jk)
\end{align*}
We also calculate the following sum.
\begin{align*}
a_k(k^2n+k^2) =& \sum_{i=1}^{kn+k}(-1)^{k^2n+k^2-i+1}a_k(i) \\
=& (-1)^ka_k(k^2n+k^2-k) + (-1)^{k+1}a_k(kn+k)
\end{align*}

Now, for odd $k$, this is where my work stops, but if $k$ is even, we can do the following.
\begin{align*}
a_k(k^2n+k^2)-a_k(k^2n+k^2-k) =& -a_k(kn+k) \\
\frac{a_k(k^2n+k^2)-a_k(k^2n+k^2-k)}{k} =& \frac{-1}{k}a_k(kn+k)
\end{align*}
Supposing there is some differentiable $\gamma_k$ that approximates $a_k$, we use Lagrange's intermediate value theorem to state that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\gamma_k(k^2n+k^2)-\gamma_k(k^2n+k^2-k)}{k} =& \frac{-1}{k}\gamma_k(kn+k) \\
\gamma_k'(\xi) =& \frac{-1}{k}\gamma_k(kn+k)
\end{align*}
for some $\xi \in [k^2n+k^2-k,k^2n+k^2]$. Which means that as we take $n$ very large, we approximately get
\begin{align*}
\gamma_k'(\xi) = \frac{-1}{k}\gamma_k \left( \frac{\xi}{k} \right).
\end{align*}
We use the method of power series to solve this DE, assuming $\gamma_k(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{(k)}_i x^i$, and we find $(i+1)\alpha^{(k)}_{i+1} = \frac{-\alpha^{(k)}_i}{k^{i+1}}$. By induction, we find $\alpha^{(k)}_i = \frac{(-1)^i \alpha^{(k)}_0}{i!k^{\frac{i^2+i}{2}}}$.

Therefore, we must have
\begin{align*}
\gamma_k(x) =& \alpha_0^{(k)} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!k^{\frac{i^2+i}{2}}} x^i
\end{align*}
Now, if you could check if for some $\alpha_0^{(k)}$, this comes close to the curve your sequence described, I would be happy.

Comment: This looks nice. Lets first check roots of $\gamma_k(x)$ against "near-zeroes" of $a_k(n)$ for $k=2$:$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}4.5&12.5&33.5&84.5&204.5&480.5&1102.5&2494.5&5568.5&12300\\2.97616&9.76228&27.1208&69.5506&169.955&402.006&928.826&2108.26&4719.32&10446.8\\51.2017\%&28.0438\%&23.5214\%&21.4942\%&20.3263\%&19.5257\%&18.6983\%&18.3201\%&17.9936\%&17.7398\%\\\end{array}$$The root $n\approx12300$ is missed by $17.74\%$, which looks a bit high? Trying to fit $\alpha_0^{(2)}$ to amplitude, I get varying results depending near which root I look, maybe because the error is a bit high.

Comment: Nevertheless, this does approximate the curve. It seems we need to compute much larger $n$ to get a better approximation. I suspect we can do similarly for odd $k$, since more generally if you looking at any real $k\gt 1.5$ the $a_k(n)$ appears to give similar curves, but with different roots and amplitudes. I also wonder if we can do better regarding errors for small $n$. To lower errors for now, I can write $f_1(k,x)$ instead of $k$ in the sum. We can tweak $f_1(k,x)\approx k$ to arbitrarily decrease the error near some root $x_0=x$. Then, we can approximate $\alpha_0^{(k)}$ more nicely.

Comment: Well, I wasn't really expecting this function to be a great approximator for $n \to \infty$, but it's at least a function that shows similar behaviour. The problem is that I estimated $\xi$ to lie at the edge of it's interval, but that surely isn't the case.

Comment: I appreciate what you've done. If you want to see visualize your approximation, we can for example: Near $x=5800$ use $\gamma_{2.037}(x)$ (black) to approximate $a_2(x)$ (green), and get that $\alpha_0^{(2)}\approx 7$: [[See the plot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG2tz.png)]. Near $x=12800$ use $\gamma_{2.033}(x)$ to approximate $a_2(x)$, and get that $\alpha_0^{(2)}\approx 7.55$: [[See the plot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mWy6.png)]. You can notice that I used $\gamma_{f_1(2,x)}$ instead of $\gamma_2$ to decrease the error of roots. Now $\alpha_0^{(2)}$ depends on $f_1(2,x)\approx2$.

Comment: Thanks! It's doing a bit better than I expected actually.